# aws ec2: how to know public ip from inside ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I created a amazon-web-services instance and used the Ubuntu 14.04 amazon machine image.

now I can ssh into that machine and use the shell to run different commands.

my question is now, how I can find out the public IP from that machine from inside that ssh-session?

I tried using

`netstat`

and

`ifconfig`

but cannot find out the public IP I locked in with via ssh.

Is there somebody who can tell me how to find out, the ip I used to ssh into the machine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to know the public IP of your aws instance?

Comment: yes, from inside the instance

Comment: curl ifconfig.me

Comment: curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been ask many time. What you need is [Instance Metadata and User Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

Just do this and refer to the mentioned documentation, you get the public ip address :

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Comment: This actually didn't work for me, I got a 404 when trying to execute the curl command.

Comment: @YaronIdan : this work out of the box for AWS EC2 instance that using standard AMI.  Unless you have network that use 169.254 or blocking rules.

Comment: @YaronIdan the URL was wrong - I edited the URL so it works and you can check the examples from the link

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHenri

Answer (score 4):

The format of your `ssh` command is sommething like

```
ssh -i "xxx.pem" ubuntu@ec2-54-252-113-980.ap-souheast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

than the public IP of your instance is **54.252.113.980**, the numbers after `ubuntu@ec2`.

Other command line options for getting the public IP on ubuntu are:

1. `curl ipecho.net/plain ; echo`
2. `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -`

Comment: yes, i know. but i need to know the ip from inside the ssh-session not from my local pc from where i connected to the instance

Comment: The public IP will always be the same unless you restart your instance. So, is there any specific need to get it from the SSH session?

Comment: i want to save the ip into a database inside the machine. i can somehow work around that but it will cost me some extra thinking

Comment: thx, your answers are correct too, but i can only give one solved flag. @mootmoot answer is nice because i can get all the other metadata too

Comment: No worries. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really just get the *Public IP* from the standard linux command

You can check the web console (but apparently its not something you want) or use the aws CLI

```
[xxx@IP-xxxx ~]# aws ec2 describe-addresses
{
    "Addresses": [
        {
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "InstanceId": "xxxx",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-xxxx",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-xxxx",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "xxxx",
            "PublicIp": "THE PUBLIC IP",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-xxxx",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "THE INTERNAL IP the instance knows"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so you see no way of finding out with which ip/address the ssh session was using from inside?

Comment: the Elastic IP is an Amazon thing and an allocation between the instance and a public IP but the instance does not know anything about it - if you download the aws tool you can find out as I show from the example - you run it from the ssh from inside the box and it gives you the public IP

Comment: ahh, i see. i'll give it a try. can you give me a hint where i can find my aws-access-key-id, aws-secret-access-key and default-region-name? the command you recommended is asking for aws configure

Comment: from the IAM console : http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1R9KDN9ISZ0HF/Where-s-my-secret-access-key